# Angular and Tel binding returns wrong data

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

When i want to call the number which is stored in Firebase i get this number in the dialpad on android:

> 2287466367

The correct number would be +419999999.

This is my markup:

```
  <a ng-href="tel:cat.phonenr"><div class="likebtn1"><img src="img/phone.png" alt=""></div></a>
```

When i try to accsess the phone number outside the ng-href i get the correct number, so the data from firebase is correct.

ie.

```
<h1 class="animated zoomIn">{{cat.phonenr}}</h1>
```

This displays the correct number.

What's my mistake? Very weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put mustache around the angular variable like this :

```
ng-href="tel:{{cat.phonenr}}"
```

So it will evaluate your value.

From angular docs :

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref